# Email notification on automatic snap upgrades

Tags: upgrade, snap, email

Apt can send you [emails](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package) for automatic (aka unattended) upgrades.

How should snap be configured to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation about emailing of changes.

But if you are an advanced user, you may able to make a snap that does that using `snapd-control` interface.

- interface source code: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/interfaces/builtin/snapd_control.go
- documentation: https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapd-control-interface